# Unable to get correct Navigation settings details for SharePoint 2013 Web using Powershell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, global-navigation, current-navigation

I am using SharePoint 2013 Site collection. I am trying to get the Navigation Setting details for each web inside the site collection using PowerShell. Using below lines of code to retrieve the same. But getting incorrect result.

$SPPubWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
$SPPubWeb.Navigation.InheritGlobal
$SPPubWeb.Navigation.InheritCurrent

Both InheritGlobal & InheritCurrent return false whereas if I see the site navigation settings page manually the web is inheriting from it's parent for global and current navigation.

Could you please guide If I am doing something wrong here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I tested with your cmdlet and it works fine. The properties change will reflects in the results I get when I change in navigation settings. Have a try to get the SP web object again and check the properties